# Pointer passing issue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I would like to change outside content by passing pointer instead of using `return` inside a method.

So I wrote some code like this:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
[self changeString:str];

//....

-(void)changeString:(NSString *)str
{
    *str = @"World";
}
```

I KNOW the above code does not work since it should have used pointer to pointer (`(NSString **)str`) to change any outside variables.

But I was wondering what is the reason the above code does not work.

**I thought `*str` should be the content that both `local str`(inside) and outside `str` are pointing to, so changing it is supposed to change the content of outside `str`.**

But Xcode gave error:

```
Assigning to 'NSString' from incompatible type 'NSString *'
```

So can anyone explain the mechanism? My `C` is rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your code:

```
-(void)changeString:(NSString *)str
{
    *str = @"World";
}
```

The type of `str` is `NSString*`. Therefore, the type of `*str` is `NSString` (to the extent that that even makes sense; read on).

The type of `@"World"` is `NSString*`. That type does not match the type of `*str`. As the compiler error said:

```
Assigning to 'NSString' from incompatible type 'NSString *'
```

Note the two different types in that error message.

Syntactically, this is akin to having a `struct foo` and trying to do:

```
struct foo* a;
struct foo b;
b = a;
```

This doesn't work because you can't assign a pointer value to a struct variable.

The problem goes deeper, though.

For structs, you *can* assign one to the other, like so:

```
struct foo a;
struct foo b;
b = a;
```

The compiler generates code to copy the values of `a` into `b`. This is usually akin to a simple `memcpy()`. This isn't a proper **semantic** copy, though, because there may be a requirement to handle some fields specially. For example, `struct foo` might contain a pointer and it may be that each instance should have its own separate pointer rather than sharing the same one. Or the pointers may require reference counting.

The situation is still more complicated with Objective-C object pointers. You may have a variable of type `NSString*` that holds a pointer to a string object. But that object is not an instance of `NSString`, itself. `NSString` is the abstract class at the root of a class cluster. There are a variety of private concrete subclasses for different specialized purposes and each string object is an instance of one of those. (There's also the public subclass `NSMutableString` and you can store a pointer to one of its concrete subclasses in any `NSString*` variable, too.)

So, `str` may point to an instance of one class while `@"World"` may be an instance of another class. They likely have different, incompatible internal layouts and sizes. A direct copy of the contents of one over the storage of the other will not work properly. It might not even fit in the allocated space.

Furthermore, in the modern Objective-C run time, Objective-C classes are no longer syntactic sugar around simple structs. In order to solve the fragile base class problem, the size and layout of an Objective-C class/instance is not assumed to be known at compile time. There are also tagged pointers, where an object pointer doesn't really point to any allocated memory; the value of the object is completely encoded within the pointer value itself.

So, the compiler doesn't even have the information necessary to emit the code for the copy. You can't even meaningfully dereference object pointer types. That's what I meant above about `NSString` not really even making sense as a proper type. There's just about nothing you can usefully do with `*str` except perhaps take its address again (`&*str`).

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference in Objective-C (and Swift as well.)

When you are passing an NSString as a parameter it's true that you are passing a pointer, but you're passing a pointer to a string object, not to an array of bytes in memory. You should not try to dereference the pointer and write into the memory. That's not how it works.

If you want to pass in a string, have it be modified, and pass back the modified result, you have a couple of choices.

tl;dr: Use a mutable string.

The details:

One option is to pass in a mutable string (class `NSMutableString`. Then change the contents of the string.

```
-(void)changeString:(NSMutableString *)str
{
    [str setString:  @"World"
}
```

In that code you are telling the string object `str` to discard it's old contents and replace them with "World". Upon return, the caller will presumably still have a reference to the string object it passed to `changeString`, but the string will now contain new contents.

The second option is to pass in a pointer to a pointer to a string:

```
-(void)changeString:(NSString **)str
{
    *str = @"World";
}
```

In this second option, you pass in a pointer to a pointer to a string. The function changes the caller's pointer to str so that it points to a different string object. This second option is risky, however. The above code would work because we are replacing the string with a string literal, which is created at compile time and doesn't get released. If instead we used code like this:

```
-(void)changeString:(NSString **)str
{
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Number %d", intVar];
    *str = newString;
}
```

Then bad things would happen. The first line would create a new string object and save it into the variable `newString`. The variable `newString` is a strong reference, so the newly created object persists for the life of the function.

However, in the next line, you copy a pointer to `newString` into the variable str, which the compiler doesn't know about. No memory management is done to make str take an owning reference to the newly created string object.

When you hit the closing brace on this function, `newString` goes out of scope, and the object it contains may be released at that moment or sometime in the near future. (It is likely placed in an autorelease pool, which means that it won't get released until the next time your program returns and visits the event loop Everything will seem ok in the calling function, and then later, bad things will happen.)

Comment: "but you're passing a pointer to a string object, not to an array of bytes in memory. You should not try to dereference the pointer and write into the memory." What I'm confused here is actually why I cannot dereference the pointer of `NSString`? I tried to dereference a `Int *` and it worked -- `*a = *b;` or `*a = 10;`

Comment: What you pass is a pointer to an immutable string object. When you try to save new data into that address, your are trying to mutate an immutable object.  An `NSString` is not the same thing as a C string. It's not a simple block of bytes in memory that contains characters. It is an object that holds a string inside it's private data store. You don't have direct access to that data store. It's opaque. All you can do is ask for the string contents.

Comment: I see, so the reason is mainly because of its immutability. Then what if I changed all the `NSString` to `NSMutableString`, and then change it to `*str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"World"];`. I still got error, why is that? (`Assigning to 'NSMutableString' from incompatible type 'NSMutableString *_Nonnull'`)
)

Comment: Objects are not passed by reference in Objective-C. Objects are passed by pointer. The pointers are passed by value just like all parameters in Objective-C.

Comment: I also tried `str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"World"];` without `*`, and it doesn't give error but it also does not change the outside `str` value.

Comment: "Then bad things would happen" - as you talk about strong references you are talking about the ARC world, and in that world bad things would not happen. Lookup `NSError **`and pass-by-writeback.

Comment: @Boris, `str` inside the method is a local variable. It's a completely different variable from the caller's. At the entry of the method, it has a copy of the pointer that the caller passed. `str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"World"];` just assigns a different pointer to that local variable. Of course it doesn't affect either the caller's variable nor the object pointed to by that variable.